ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' - When trying to use GeminiAPI
This is my code:
import google.generativeai as genai
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()
api_key = os.getenv("GeminiAPI_KEY")
genai.configure(api_key=api_key)
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')


def get_gemini_summary(book_name, author_name):
    prompt = f"Summarize the book {book_name} by {author_name} in 5 sentences or less"
    response = model.generate_content(prompt)
    print(response.text)


def main():
    get_gemini_summary("The Great Gatsby", "F. Scott Fitzgerald")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I keep getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' in line 1 when trying to import generativeai as genai.
Can anyone help?
Things I already tried:

uninstalling and installing: google.generativeai
uninstalling and installing: google-generativeai
Ensured my interpreter version is fine (3.9)
Tried different IDEs

After some trial and error, I figured that the problem was in my Python version and my venv.
I switched to Python 3.10, but it might work in other version as well.

Edit your question and include the requirements.txt file. Which version of Python and which OS? Show the output from the command pip list. On some systems, it is pip3 list.

You're absolutely right. I played with the versions a little bit and it works now.

The correct pip is
pip install  google.generativeai

Code
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import google.generativeai as genai
import os

load_dotenv()
genai.configure(api_key=os.getenv("API_KEY"))
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-pro-latest')
response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life in two sentences")
print(response.text)

try doing a
pip list 

to make sure you dont have anything strange hanging out there are a few third party libraries that look like google but are not the official library.

This is exactly what I did. I still get this error where it doesn't recognize the line google.generativeai.
I tried deleting and recreating the virtual environment but it also didn't work.
Any suggestions?

I was running python file_name.py. When I ran python3 file_name.py, it worked.
